# Github PR change compare from branch to master without many changes

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have a PR in Github compared against a branch A. The git branch was also built off of this branch A.

I want to update this comparison back to master and `$ git pull origin master` on the branch. However this causes thousands of merge conflicts even though the PR is less than 100 lines.

**Other Options**

- I considered cherrypicking but then I lose the comments and history on the PR.
- I could go by hand and manually merge all the conflicts.

Does anyone know the best way to do this? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do either of the following w/o losing history

- Rebase your feature branch with master

> ```
> git rebase origin/master
> ```

- Merge master into your own branch

> `git merge origin/master`